# Emailing : Gmail change my text in link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, gmail, newsletter

I have a big problem with gmail who change my text into a link.
I created a email for my company but gmail changed the span "test.com" into a link.

```
<span class="tt1">Lorem ipsum<br><br>dolor sit amet<br><br>on test.com<br></span>
```

I don't want a link can u help me?

Thx

Comment: You might try replacing the period in test.com with `&#46;`.  If I understand your question, it's that gmail is automatically parsing that into a link when you don't want it.  I'm guessing it's because there's a `.com` there.  Try that and see if it works.

Comment: What version of android are u using for this?

Comment: This is intended for IOS, but may work for gmail: https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices

Comment: I know this skill but it is not effective thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now `test&#46;com` doesn't work with gmail, we must use `test&#173;.com`

Answer (score 3):

You can't stop Gmail from turning it into a link, but you can make it a link that goes nowhere and style it to **not appear** like a link and Gmail will respect your styles. example:

```
<span class="tt1">Lorem ipsum<br><br>dolor sit amet<br><br>on <a href="" class="no-link">test.com</a><br></span>
```

add css

```
.no-link { color:#000; text-decoration:none; cursor:default; }
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding inline styles to the link/anchor, so then you know for sure the styles are being applied. Email is a funny thing in that even if you include a stylesheet, it isn't guaranteed to be followed (every client is different).

Comment: yeah inline styles in emails work best.  since this was a Gmail only issue though it shouldn't be a problem - Gmail's good with stylesheets in my experience.

Comment: though now i realize making it a link means the styling of the link will need to be applied in all browsers. in other words you are correct dward

Answer (score 1):

this issue is related to the Gmail email client.

try using the [Html code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for "."

```
<span class="tt1">Lorem ipsum<br><br>dolor sit amet<br><br>on test&#46;com<br></span>
```

But now i remember, using Gmail client in versions prior to Android 4.0 filter all the links of url and email accounts on the Gmail template.

Other option to disable the link in your email account:

```
test<span>@</span>email.com
```

Answer (score 1):

That is something Gmail handles and since it's an email, there isn't much you can do because javascript isn't an option. You could try inserting your URL/domain like this `test&#46;com`, but that likely won't change the outcome. You might just have to live with it in Gmail. If you can't, I recommend you not include your domain name.

As a side note, Gmail will also auto-link telephone numbers, addresses and even events.

Comment: Hello, 

Now test&#46;com doesn't work with gmail, we must use test&#173;.com

Thx,

Answer (score 0):

## Desired Outcome

When writing HTML for emails, represent text which names emails as raw, unformatted text.

## Problem

Gmail automatically transforms email addresses into email-creation links (using the mailto: prefix in the href attribute of an a element).

## Solution

Add a wrapper around the email which should exist as raw text.

```html
<a
   href="javascript:void(0);"
   style="color:#000; text-decoration:none; cursor:default;"
>
unclickable@gmail.com
</a>
```